# Why doesn't "Did you mean" work on Stack Overflow?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search

Assume I search for this (with typo):

> unicode special cahracters

### Results on apple.stackexchange.com:

Then, on apple.stackexchange.com I will get [0 results but with a nice suggestion which has 32 results](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=unicode+special+cahracters):
[image]

### Results on stackoverflow.com:

On stackoverflow.com I will get [0 results **without** any suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unicode+special+cahracters):
[image]

If Stack Overflow had been working the same way as Ask Different, it would have resulted in a suggestion with 3,495 results: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unicode+special+characters

Comment: @AndréKool Seasoned Advice is unlikely to search for unicode special cahracters. But just like Ask Different, [Super User is working correctly](https://superuser.com/search?q=unicode+special+cahracters), so I believe the problem is on Stack Overflow only.

Comment: *I want to decorate my cake with some chocolate unicode special cahracters. Does anyone have suggestions for some that work best?*

Comment: Far too many posts to plow through to find a better match, surely.  Whomever worked on Search is in witness protection, doubtful you'll hear anything.

Comment: Must be a deliberate choice, it is active on MSO to my surprise.

Comment: it does work for some [search terms](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cahracterd&mixed=0) so it is not switched off.

Comment: @rene interestingly, if you stick *"unicode"* in front of that, you get *"[unicod character](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unicode+cahracterd)'"* (yes, no *"e"* is intentional)

Comment: @rene Hmm.. It doesn't seem to really work even with your example, it asks: "_Did you mean: __chracter___" = ).

Comment: @Teemu rene means that the feature in itself is active. Now, regarding the quality of the suggestions, please refer to the second sentence of Hans Passant comment.

Comment: It may be broken for suggestions with more than x results.

Comment: @NickA unicod, the elusive prehistoric ancestor of unicorns that lived in the ocean... (I can't get myself to link a narwhal)

Comment: TBH, I rarely use SO search feature because it's not too good IMO. I usually use google search with `site:stackoverflow.com` instead.

Comment: @NickA ah yes, the Unicod language, an ancient language that consisted only of letters that can be created with a single fish. I'm glad it fell out of use, it stunk.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This *is* enabled on Stack Overflow - [here's a query that produces a suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=headerz+sent):

[image: Search for headerz sent asks did you mean: header sent]

But this *doesn't* work for a lot of searches that you'd expect it to:

[image: Headers already setn produces no results, no suggestions]

And that includes your example of "unicode special cahracters". A hint as to why can be found by searching for "cahracters" alone:

[image: Ask Different produces no results and a suggestion] vs [image: Stack Overflow produces 81 results]

We're using Elastic's built-in phrase suggester for this, which... does not handle this sort of situation very well. The top suggestion returned on Stack Overflow is actually "unicod special charact" - which isn't even slightly an improvement (but yes, as Nick and rene observed in the comments every one of those terms produces results by itself).

We have plans to augment this with more traditional (and... effective) forms of typo correction in the future, which should help a lot. Until then... I guess thank editors who take the time to correct these misspellings.